# Sequence of constant functions converges to constant in $L^p$?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose you have a sequence $f_i$ of constant functions. Given that $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f_i = f$ in $L^p(B)$ where $B$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I'd like to show that $f$ must be constant as well in the $L^p$ sense (a.e.)

My approach: $f$ is constant a.e. means that there exists a constant $C$ such that $\mu\{x : f(x)\ne C\}=0$. So the converse would be that for all constants $C$ we have $\mu\{x : f(x)\ne C\} > 0$. Then to get the result I want to get something like there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\mu\{x : f(x) > C+\delta\} > 0$ or $\mu\{x : f(x) < C-\delta \} > 0$. But I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Why not try to get a candidate for $f$?  I mean, show that the values of $f_i$ must be Cauchy in the scalar field. Then use the scalar limit to define $f$, and show it works and is unique in the $L^p$ sense.

Comment: What does it mean for $f_i$ to be Cauchy in scalar field? I know they're Cauchy in the $L^p$ sense but I don't know that this implies Cauchy-ness in any other sense.

Comment: I mean, if $f_i$ are real-valued constant functions with  each $f_i(x) = c_i$ for some $c_i \in \mathbb R$, then the $c_i$ should be Cauchy in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Very nice, thank-you!